# apache: don't have permission to access / on this server. when I am using virtualhost

Tags: apache, vhosts

For example, the document root of `virtualHost` is `/var/www`, and server name is `aaa.com`. 
However, apache will tell me `forbidden` if I access the server with `localhost` and `aaa.com`. If I change the `Directory` option in `http.conf` to `/var/www`, apache will work well. I don't know why?

I want to set `Directory` option in every `httpd-vhosts.conf`, not in `httpd.conf`, how I can do it?

Here is my `http.conf`:

[image]

Here is my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

[image]

Comment: You have a mistype in `http.conf` - <Directory "/var/Wwww/"> (4 w`s)

Comment: you should have a default host and the extra virtual host settings with their own `DocumentRoot` and other own settings. If these settings are after each other, what's the problem? You could be more specific, your question is a bit unclear to me. So, what if you put the "default" host settings to the file `httpd-vhosts.conf`, AND after that, you put the other `VirtualHost` settings too. EDIT: oh yeah, I just saw webbandit's comment, he's absolutely right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `http.conf` file you should define options for only `<Directory />`. All the options of VirtualHosts you should define in `httpd-vhosts.conf` files. Something like:

httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

<Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
ServerName aaa.com
DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www>
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 6):

This configuration was valid for apache version 2.2

First check your apache version by typing `apachectl -V` in your terminal.

If it shows something like this

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-04-18T14:20:05
```

then your apache version has updated but the conf you are using is deprecated.

So instead of

**2.2 configuration:**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

use this:

**2.4 configuration:**

```
Require all granted
```

For further documentation related to the upgrade, follow the official docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

**2.4 configuration:**

```
<Directory />

Options All
AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```